# ASP.Net MVC Cookies not persisting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

Essentially I'm trying to set a cookie after a user logs in to persist their username for the next time they log in.  Here's my code to set the cookie.  When I look at the site cookies in Firefox as soon as the cookie is set, it shows the sessionID cookie, but not the one I just set.  When I check the headers in Fiddler, I don't see it setting the cookie, only my sessionID cookie.

```
HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("username", model.UserName);
hc.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(hc);
```

Here is where I check to see if the cookie exists.

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["username"] != null)
```

Here's the full context of the methods in question

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["username"] != null)
        return View(new LogOnModel { UserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["username"].Value });
    else
        return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("username", model.UserName);
            hc.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(hc);

            FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to go through System.Web.[...] to work with the Request and Response objects. They're already exposed by the controller. Although I doubt it, you may have issues from how you're doing it now because you're not in context with the actual MVC app. @Adam's answer should be your fix though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add to response.cookies not request.cookies

Comment: Awesome, I knew it was something simple I was overlooking.